# Problem with adding angular-fontawesome library on stackblitz

Tags: angular, stackblitz

When I add a library, it shows me an error on stackblitz.

> Error in ~/src/main.ts ngcc failed to run on
> @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.7.0.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wz89c7

Am I the only one to have this problem?

Comment: I got the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to disable "Enable Ivy" in the settings. Which result in:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": false,
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
"strictInjectionParameters": true
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I changed the package.json to use "latest" instead of "" for fontawesome and it works.

"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "latest",